# Armies in Game of Thrones

Tags: game-of-thrones

How does Daenerys' army keep multiplying in size after every battle in *game of Thrones*?

Example:

1. S8E3 Battle with the NightKing - Dothraki 1000s present, Unsullied 1000s
2. S8E3 Last 5 minutes - Dothraki - below 10, Unsullied - below 10
3. S8E4 Cremation Scene - Dothraki 100s, Unsullied 100s
4. S8E5 Kings Landing FaceOff -  Dothraki Up to 500+, Unsullied 500+
5. S8E6 Daenerys' Speech -  Dothraki 1000s, Unsullied 1000s

Do the creators have a reason for multiplying the armies every episode?

Comment: While there is no doubt that the numbers being shown seemed inconsistent, I must ask what evidence you have that the people visible in scenes 2-4 of your list represent the total population of the army?  Using #4 as an example, how do we know there weren't thousands of Unsullied and Dothraki attacking other gates (there are 7 gates, I think), providing a rear guard in case Cersei got reinforcements, standing in reserve waiting to charge in if the Lannisters rallied and counter attacked?

Comment: Numbers are approximate guess figure of what was shown. But the question is not about the exact number, it's about why the armies are multiplying exponentially after war scenes

Comment: And my comment had nothing do with exact numbers.  Your question is based on the assumption that the soldiers shown in each of these scenes are the only soldiers that exist in Dany's army.  I am suggesting that your assumptions may not be entirely correct.

Comment: In general war scenarios, logically speaking, Let's say you start a war with 1000, after 2 wars, there is a high possibility that more than half your army is destroyed. But here the armies are gaining numbers after the war scenes, Was that a mistake or was there a reason for it.

Comment: Once again, you are claiming that the numbers have increased.  And once again I am saying that this claim can only be true if you assume that every soldier is visible in every scene.  If you cannot provide evidence that each of these scenes show us all of Dany's army then logically speaking you cannot claim that the size of her army has increased.

Comment: @krb There's at least one example I think it works for - the Battle of Winterfell. The Dothraki charge was visible, shown as the entire force (battle plans, the fact that you wouldn't use cavalry on the walls etc.), the Inside the Episode spells out that it's basically the end of the Dothraki, and then we cut to the start of the next episode, and apparently half of them are still alive. I would argue that's a pretty strong case that what we see on the screen is portrayed to give an accurate interpretation (at least in Episode 3).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This simplest answer is that at no time during the series do we actually see the full size of Daenerys' army. So in some scenes we see a small portion while in others we see a larger portion.

[According to this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-sizes-of-the-various-armies-in-Game-of-Thrones-at-the-end-of-season-7), Daenarys came to Westeros with approximately 116,000 soldiers. 100,000 of those were Dothraki riders. The remaining were 8,000 seasoned Unsullied, 5,000 Unsullied-in-training, and a combination of other smaller battalions.

Now that is a lot of people. Even if we're generous and say that half her army was gone after the Battle of Winterfell (which would arguably make it the bloodiest battle in history), that would still leave 50,000 men fighting at her will. That is still a really massive army.  I'd wager at no point during season 8 do we see more than a couple hundred at once.

Comment: While this doesn't invalidate the points in your answer, there were also earlier battles that might have reduced her army to some degree.